TV movie, amputations to build a super athlete
I have very faint memories of a TV movie I watched in the UK in the 1980s.
There's (I think) a montage of short clips near the start,the one I remember shows a runner is jogging along in a tracksuit, the next image he is lying on a hospital gurney staring in horror at two bandaged stumps where his legs used to be.
The plotline I recall is somebody is doing like a Dr Frankenstein but with living body parts. I'm not sure if the villain wanted to create a super athlete  body for himself and get his brain put in or if he was making a deadly assassin.
I thought it might have actually been a 'The Avengers' or 'Man from Uncle' story that my memory has confused but I can't find a match.

sounds like an Avengers plot ... could also  be  Twilight Zone

Are you sure this isn't The Six Million Dollar Man?

@Paulie-D I'm certain it wasn't, I saw a clip of Lee Majors on YouTube this morning and that reminded me of this mystery movie

I mean, seeing a clip of Lee Majors would certainly remind me of a movie starting Lee Majors. Your memory could be of the third pilot movie, The Solid Gold Kidnapping.

This is Scream and Scream Again, a British film from 1970 with Vincent Price, Peter Cushing, and Christopher Lee.
The film has three plotlines that run in alternate scenes and eventually converge - the one you describe about a runner who has been kidnapped and wakes to find his legs have been amputated, one involving an Eastern European spy making shady deals with British intelligence, and one about police investigating a serial rapist. The spy and the rapist both turn out to be among the the experimental composite beings created by a secret research project out of body parts from multiple people.



